# How do you replace the last comma with "and" in a comma-separated string?

Tags: string, vbscript, asp-classic

I need to use VBScript to insert an "and" into a string before the last item in a comma-separated list.

```
strList = "512, 66, 1820, 1235, 7, 4918"
```

needs to become...

```
strReList = "512, 66, 1820, 1235, 7 and 4918"
```

I've looked around SO and have found this question answered for javascript, C# and other languages, but never VBS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with the `StrReverse()` and `Replace()` functions:

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim strList: strList = "512, 66, 1820, 1235, 7, 4918"
strReList = StrReverse(strList)
strReList = Replace(strReList, ", ", " dna", 1, 1)
strList = StrReverse(strReList)
Call Response.Write(strList)
```

Output:

```
512, 66, 1820, 1235, 7 and 4918
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a regular expression:

```vb
strList = "512, 66, 1820, 1235, 7, 4918"

Set rx = New RegExp
rx.Pattern = "(.*),\s*(\d+)"
strListMod = rx.Replace(strList, "$1 and $2")

wscript.echo strListMod
```

Output:

```
512, 66, 1820, 1235, 7 and 4918
```

Comment: RegEx is so cool! Good reminder that RegEx isn't just for JS. Thanks for contributing this.